# Prevent user from logging in in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I have created a custom login form and I want to prevent the user from logging in for this case:

I have one field `password_changed_date` in the `users` table.
I want to compare that date with the current date, and if the difference is more than 6 months, the user should be redirected to other page. How can I do that?

Comment: Couple of possible approaches.  The easiest would be to plugin your own password encoder which would throw some sort of password expired exception.  Catch the exception and redirect.  A more "official" way might be to create your own [guard authenticator](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/guard_authentication.html).

Answer (score 2):

In order to prevent a user from logging in when their credentials expired you can use the [`AdvancedUserIternface`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/AdvancedUserInterface.php). Among other things this interface provides a method called `isCredentialsNonExpired()` that would fit your need. These methods are automatically checked by Symfony's security component when you implement that interface. For all other methods required by the interface you can just always return true if you don't need them.

This will cause your login to fail and should redirect you back to the login form, just like if you entered a wrong password. In your loginAction you can use the `AuthenticationUtils` to get the last error using `getLastAuthenticationError()`. This would allow you to react to the error. For example you could check the error message and then perform a redirect to the special page you want to display.